# Navigating from child component to parent component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a parent component with several children:

```
  // more routes here

  {
    path: '/organisatie',
    name: 'Organisation',
    meta: { breadCrumb: 'Organisatie' },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "organisations" */ '../views/Organisation.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/personen',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "people" */ '../views/People.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'People',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "listpeople" */ '../views/ListPeople.vue'),
        meta: { breadCrumb: 'Personen' },
      },
      {
        path: '/personen/:id',
        name: 'Person',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "person" */ '../views/Person.vue'),
        meta: { breadCrumb: 'Persoon' },
        children: [
          {
            path: '/personen/:id/edit',
            name: 'Edit-user',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "editperson" */ '../views/EditPerson.vue'),
            meta: { breadCrumb: 'Bewerken' },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

I can navigate to `mywebsite.com/personen/id`. But if I go to another page via a router-link, say 'organisatie', the URL becomes `mywebsite.com/personen/organisatie` instead of `mywebsite.com/organisatie`.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Edit: I'm using a custom component from [Vue Language Router](https://github.com/adbrosaci/vue-lang-router) which I dynamically add my links to: `<localized-link to="item.link"></localized-link>`

```
items: [
  { link: 'organisatie'},
]
```

Comment: How do you use `router-link`?

Comment: try `<router-link to="/organisatie" />` or without slash (`/`) i.e., `<router-link to="organisatie" />`

Comment: @User28 See my edit.

Comment: You should always start url with `/` so it should be `{ link: '/organisatie' }`. Or use with name `items: [{ name: 'Organisation' }]` and `:to="item"`.

Comment: @User28 Alright, I changed this and it fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good idea to repeat parent path in a child path.
Here is an example for nested routes;
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Can you try the code below? Of course you should fix router-links aswell.

```
// more routes here

  {
    path: '/organisatie',
    name: 'Organisation',
    meta: { breadCrumb: 'Organisatie' },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "organisations" */ '../views/Organisation.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/personen',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "people" */ '../views/People.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'People',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "listpeople" */ '../views/ListPeople.vue'),
        meta: { breadCrumb: 'Personen' },
      },
      {
        path: '/:id',
        name: 'Person',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "person" */ '../views/Person.vue'),
        meta: { breadCrumb: 'Persoon' },
        children: [
          {
            path: '/:id/edit',
            name: 'Edit-user',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "editperson" */ '../views/EditPerson.vue'),
            meta: { breadCrumb: 'Bewerken' },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: I did this so the URL is `mywebsite/personen/id` if I do it the way above the URL is `mywebsite/id`.

Comment: @deRaaf You mean when you navigate? If yes I think the problem is how you navigate not how you define routes.

Comment: Can you post your router link command for this case?